# CSS Transparent Border Problem In Firefox 4?

Tags: css, transparent, firefox4

I'm trying to create a pure CSS triangle for a tooltip. All browsers looks fine except for the latest Firefox 4. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.arrow {
    border:50px solid;
    border-color:#eee transparent transparent transparent;
    display:block;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    top:50%;
    right:50%;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border:1px solid #000; height:400px; width:400px; margin:50px auto; position:relative;">
    <span class="arrow"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Firefox 4 Screenshot:***

[image: Firefox 4 screenshot]

**Other Browsers Screenshot:**

[image]

As you can see in Firefox 4, it has something like a border. Is it a Firefox bug or this is really the behavior?

How can I achieve a pure CSS triangle without that visible border in FF4? Also, I need the other 3 colors to be transparent because this triangle will overlap some elements.

Comment: I'm using FF4 and I don't get this weird behavior that you describe. You are not using FF4 Beta or something?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Using Firefox 4/Windows 7, there is no "border", and it looks like the other browsers.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 4.0.1 in Windows 7, I have also tried in Windows XP FF 4.0.1

Comment: If using dark color such as red, the border is not visible. But if using light color such as #eee, it's very visible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

if `transparent` is not work for you then use `rgba` may be that's work.

Write:

```
.arrow {
    border-color:#eee rgba(255,255,255,0)  rgba(255,255,255,0)  rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

Comment: Still it has a visible border like the screenshot.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. " border-color:#eee rgba(255,255,255,0)  rgba(255,255,255,0)  rgba(255,255,255,0); " will do the trick.

Comment: Note: rgba does not work in all browsers you might want to test it in IE

Comment: I put: `border-color:#eee transparent transparent transparent;
 border-color:#eee rgba(255,255,255,0)  rgba(255,255,255,0)  rgba(255,255,255,0);` I think it's safe?

Comment: +1 yes the trick work in IE because IE support transparent not rgba

Comment: Thanks! I've been frustrated by this problem for a while.

Answer (score 11):

Okay I could see the problem, and found out that if you change the border style to "outset" if will be fixed in FF4, and works in IE9 too.

That would give you something like this:

```
.arrow {
     border:50px outset transparent ;
     border-top:#eee 50px solid;
     display:block;
     height:0;
     width:0;
     top:50%;
     right:50%;
     position:absolute;
}
```

PS. I'm on Vista with the newest firefox stable.

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UFSpd/1/

Comment: I have tried the "outset" border-type before but the problem is it is not the true color anymore. #eee will become $f6f6f6

Comment: The "outset" border type will have true colors on right and bottom sides, but the top and left will produce different color.

Comment: Did you use my code, that seems to be working here, #eee is still #eee and they do not have true colors see here: http://jsfiddle.net/UFSpd/2/

Comment: Btw tested the color in photoshop it is still #eeeeee

Comment: Yes I tested in Photoshop, it become #f6f6f6. I also tried that workaround before but I think it's only Safari that don't change the color. Other browsers will produce a lighter color if using "outset"

Comment: Note that the top border that makes the triangle is still solid "border-top:#eee 50px solid;"

Comment: Yep you are doing a thing wrong with the border styles http://jsfiddle.net/HVam7/2/ updated it to be like my example and now it works :)